# Compute Odds ratio per standard deviation

Tags: logistic, standard-deviation, odds-ratio, epidemiology

I have odds ratio per unit change in variable. I want to convert it into odds ratio per unit standard deviation change in variable.

Comment: If you decide to multiply the coefficient by the SD of the explanatory variable, be sure to multiply the regression coefficient on the log-odds scale and not the odds ratio. Exponentiate the coefficient after multiplication to get the odds ratio per one SD increase in $x$.